# Open-source forensic analysis tools to analyze full-node's local copy of Bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, open-source, chainanalysis, request

Are there any open source alternatives to [Chainalysis Reactor](https://www.chainalysis.com/chainalysis-reactor/) for doing forensic analysis of a local copy of the full Bitcoin blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

No I have not seen any open source projects similar to Chainalysis Reactor. Even explorers like [OXT](https://oxt.me) that are helpful in on-chain analysis are not open source.

It will be a great project if someone can create such open source tools because sometimes you need to break things to improve them. Ignoring tools used by companies like Chainalysis doesn't improve anything.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has written a tool to analyze the blockchain offline. There are many full-nodes out that that have the full chain stored locally.

Comment: Problem is everyone hates people who do chain analysis. So nobody wants to waste time on a project that will be shared as a bad actor even though it will help in improving privacy.

Comment: But as you say, "sometimes you need to break things to improve them".

Comment: Can't Bitcoin Core's terminal do basic blockchain analysis, such as with `-txindex` enabled?

Comment: What kind of analysis are you looking for?

Comment: what blockchain explorers do: find all blocks transactions with a particular address appear in, get balance of an address, trace flow to/from an address

Comment: You can use open source block explorers with Bitcoin Core: 1. https://github.com/mempool/mempool 2. https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora 3. https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer

Answer (score 1):

[BlockSci](https://github.com/citp/BlockSci) might be relevant, though "As of November 2020", it "is no longer actively maintained".

Abstract of [a paper by one of its devs](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity20/presentation/kalodner):

> Analysis of blockchain data is useful for both scientific research and commercial applications. We present BlockSci, an open-source software platform for blockchain analysis. BlockSci is versatile in its support for different blockchains and analysis tasks. It incorporates an in-memory, analytical (rather than transactional) database, making it orders of magnitudes faster than using general-purpose graph databases. We describe BlockSci's design and present four analyses that illustrate its capabilities, shedding light on the security, privacy, and economics of cryptocurrencies.